# Overloading << for type inside another class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading

I have a typedef inside a class and I would like to overload the `operator<<` for it to be able to print it in `ostream`. However, the compiler cannot find the overloaded operator. How can I declare it so that it works?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

template <class C>
struct K {

    typedef std::set<C> Cset;

    Cset s;
    // and many more elements here

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& oo, const Cset& ss){
        typename Cset::const_iterator it=ss.begin();
        oo << "[";
        for(; it!=ss.end(); ++it) oo << (*it) << ",";
        oo << "]";
        return oo;
    }

    void DoSomething(){
        // do something complicated here
        cout << s << endl;
        // do something complicated here
    }

};


int main(){
    K <int> k;
    k.s.insert(5);
    k.s.insert(3);
    k.DoSomething();

}
```

> gcc version 4.4.5 20101112 (Red Hat 4.4.5-2) (GCC)

Comment: Is the reason why you want it defined inside the class so that the function remains invisible outside `struct K`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight And is defining it outsid a good idea? I mean, can it collide with a smiliar definition by someone else (in different header file for instance?) Anyways, this seems to work, thanks a lot!

Comment: His code compiles and runs fine for me on VC 2010 & G++ 3.3.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a `friend` function is defined `inline` and there is no forward declaration outside the class, it is only found by `ADL`. However, your overload will never be found by `ADL` as it does not involve `K` arguments (note that `K<int>::CSet` is a *typedef* for `std::set<C>`).

Comment: The argument is K<int>::CSet. So it does involve K. Anyway, the code compiles and runs for me on VC 2010 & G++ 3.3.3. Not that that proves it's good code, but ..

Comment: @user93353: `K<int>::CSet` is a _typedef_ for `std::set<C>` and `C` is `int`, not `K`.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness: final version of the code for `operator<<`:

```
template <class T, class U>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& oo, const std::set <T,U> & ss){
    typename std::set <T,U> ::const_iterator it=ss.begin();
    oo << "[";
    if(it!=ss.end()) oo << (*it++);
    while(it!=ss.end()) oo << "," << (*it++);
    oo << "]";
    return oo;
}
```